# Any idea why Unlock-ADAccount is so slow?

Tags: performance, powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script that looks at 10 servers to see if an account is locked out and then tries to unlock it. Both the search for the status and the unlocking itself are terribly slow...about 10 seconds each. Partial code below. Would hope each call would only take < 1 second.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $servers.length; $i++) {
  try {
    $lockstatus = Get-ADUser -Server $servers[$i] -Identity $username -Properties LockedOut
  } catch...
```

and also to only unlock those servers that show account locked...

```
  for ($i=0; $i -lt $servers.length; $i++) {
    if ($serverslock[$i]) {
      Write-Host "Updating" $servers[$i] "..."
      try {
        Unlock-ADAccount -Server $servers[$i] -Identity $username
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why do you check multiple servers? Account lockout changes (including manually unlocking an account) triggers [urgent replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775412(WS.10).aspx), so there's no need to do it on more than one server, as long as the PDC Emulator is online

Comment: It seems that at times the servers get out of sync so some show locked while others do not. Don't have time to wait for servers to replicate...need unlock to happen immediately.